# Mongoose schema.post events broken in versions >= 4.8.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

In a node app that uses mongoose, I defined some mongoose middleware hooks like this:

```
mongoose.model('MyModel').schema.post('save', function(document) {
    // following is executed in 4.7.9 but not 4.8.0
    console.log('saved');
});
```

These work perfectly well in mongoose versions up to and including 4.7.9 but if I update mongoose to 4.8.0 in my application, then with no other changes, these hooks fail to be invoked at all.  There are no warnings or errors.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html suggests that the way to define these hooks hasn't changed.  Is there something different I need to do in 4.8.0+ to retain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you need to declare middleware *before* creating the model:

```
let MySchema = new mongoose.Schema(...);

MySchema.post('save', ...);

let MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', MySchema);
```

See this as well: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4971#issuecomment-279238187

Comment: yes, looks like I was inadvertently relying on undocumented behaviour that was changed, thanks.